# Using inner join and UPDATE, why can't i use this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM encomendas
INNER JOIN armazem ON encomendas.id_peca = armazem.id_peca
UPDATE armazem, encomendas 
SET armazem.quantidade_armazem = (armazem.quantidade_armazem - encomendas. quantidade), encomendas.estado ='concluido'
WHERE encomendas.estado = 'pendente' 
      AND (armazem.quantidade_armazem >= encomendas.quantidade)
ORDER BY encomendas.id
```

Can't seem to be able to join 2 different tables and update their values upon a `WHERE` condition

this is the error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UPDATE" LINE 4: UPDATE armazem,
>   encomendas SET armazem.quantidade_armazem = ...^

Comment: Edit your question copy the error

Comment: Because it's invalid SQL. You have a SELECT with a JOIN (which is a single operation) followed by an UPDATE (which is a separate operation) that tries to update two tables at once (which doesn't work, because it's not valid), and you can't use an ORDER BY in an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want to do?

```
UPDATE encomendas, armazem
SET armazem.quantidade_armazem = (armazem.quantidade_armazem - encomendas.quantidade), 
    encomendas.estado ='concluido'
WHERE encomendas.id_peca = armazem.id_peca 
  AND encomendas.estado = 'pendente' 
  AND (armazem.quantidade_armazem >= encomendas.quantidade)
```

Comment: yes this is what im trying to do but i dont think its possible, i just ran this query and it give me this error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 2: INNER JOIN armazem

Comment: @RenatoFonseca It's not tested. But I made a slight change. How bout now?

Comment: since this took more time than i initaly entended to emply I ended up using an alternative by using 2 separate querys to reach the same conclusion. So im dropping this question. Either thanks for ur answers